# Side scroll game with 8000xScreen_Height, which technique is best

Tags: game-mechanics, cocos2d

I got one new requirement for iOS side scroll game with screen size : 8000xScreen_Height

For this, tileMap is best or normal texture based is best? I need to use parallax background too.

Help me to find right technique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK max texture size is still 2048x2048 on newer, and 1024x1024 on older devices. So you *have to* split up your texture in any case.

Comment: @bummzack, yes that we know...our game screen size is arround 8000 with multiple texture..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I will talk how I render those things in my game.

My background (parallax) is divided in four segments. The game starts with the three segments on the screen, but as the player moves forward, the forth start showing up and the first starts disappearing (in the left side). Once it completes disappear, I move that segment to the front, and keep doing it. Basically, an infinite loop with four segments. The smaller the segments, less draws you do offscreen and faster draw times.

For the platforms I just create a big circle around my character, and if the "tile" is in this circle, then I render it, otherwise, ignore. It's a very fast radius distance check ;)

Personal opinion: I used my own level design tool to create the game level, where I used normal texture with variant objects size. But, if I were to do it again, I would use tileMaps, just because its simplify a lot of math and implementations.